# solid angles of an n-simplex

Tags: geometry, simplex, solid-angle

Do there exist formulae relating the n-th dimensional solid angles of an n-simplex to either the n-th order dihedral angles, the volume of the n-1 dimensional facets, or the side lengths of the simplex?

Comment: I can just address you to [this paper](pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/hopf-samelson.pdf) and to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452777) mentioning the Hypersine function

Comment: Interesting. I have read over a bit but I am still unsure how the Hypersine function relates to the solid angle.

Comment: I am also still under the process of learning about it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Wolfram Mathworld you'll find a page on [hypersine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersine.html). (In order to grasp the there provided definition wrt. parallelotopes, you best would apply it to a 2D parallelogram first. Then it becomes nothing but the area formula thereof, which has been resolved to the "normal" sine of the dihedral angle.) There too is provided the searched for formula, relating the hypersine of a hypersolid angle $V_0$ of a hypersimplex quite nicely to the set of its dihedral angles $\alpha_{i,j}$:

[image]

(In fact there was a recent quest of mine within MO about the [hypersolid angles of the 3 regular polytopes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350222/addition-theorems-for-hypersine), which you might be interested in too. That question there indeed had been occurred to me by a comment to my other answer in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452777/are-there-such-things-as-infinite-dimensional-regular-polytopes), mentioned by @G.Cab.)

--- rk

Comment: I am still quite confused. Are you saying that $V_0$ IS the n-dimensional solid angle defined by the ratio of the surface 'hyper-volume' of an n-dimensional hypersphere to its whole surface hyper-volume? If so, do you happen to know of an easy to follow proof of this? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, $V_0$ indeed IS the hypersolid corner angle. It is more that the "sin" function displayed in the above formula rather is the hypersine function for sure, whereas the "cos" functions are the "normal" trigonometric functions of 2D geometry. Moreover the hypersine function is being defined, as provided in the Wolfram Mathworld link, by means of the there given volume surface ratio wrt. the spanned parallelotope.

Comment: Oh okay, i'm guessing that means you cant just take the $\arcsin$ of the $\sin V_0$ and return the solid angle. Does there exist an inverse function for the hypersine to retrieve the solid angle?